# Replace empty values as 0 instead of null while joining two tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have join two tables t1 and t2. The output produces some null records since there is no data in the table t2. Instead of showing **null** I want to show **0** since I have to perform some arithmetic operation in the crystal reports.
please help me.....

Comment: ISNULL(t2.col1,0) it will do the trick

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930810/sql-replace-all-nulls this link also has the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample example

```
declare @t table (ID int)
declare @t1 table (ID int)

insert into @t (id) values (1)

select t.ID,ISNULL(TT.ID,0)id  from @t t
LEFT JOIN @t1 tt
ON t.ID = tt.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `COALESCE` function which automatically replace `null` values as `0`.
Sample

```
SELECT COALESCE(total_amount, 0) from #Temp1
```